# Probability with a deck of cards

Tags: probability, card-games

Let's say you pull 9 cards in a row without replacement from a normal deck of 52 cards.

What is the probability that you will pull a triple, do example you pull a triple 3.

They don't have to be in a row, they just have to be in the pull of 9 cards.

Comment: So with a triple, you mean cards with the same rank?

Comment: Does a four of a kind count as a triple?

Comment: More to the point, what have you tried?  This looks like a (somewhat messy) application of Inclusion-Exclusion.